# Can I instantiate a superclass and have a particular subclass be instantiated based on the parameters supplied

Tags: java, javascript, json, inheritance, gson

I am using Google's GSON package http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

I am converting JSON to Java.

I have this fragment of code where I do the conversion.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<QueryProperty>>() {}.getType();
Collection<QueryProperty> queryProperties = gson.fromJson(query, collectionType);
```

My QueryProperty class has these fields (with getters/setters):

```
int id;
String uri;
String name;
Set<QueryValue> values;
String selected;
```

The QueryValue class had these fields (with getters/setters) perviously:

```
int id;
String uri;
String name;
```

I now want to be able to have different `types` of QueryValue.

I want to add a NumericQueryValue class (subclass of QueryValue), so I can pass in a set of bounds with which to query the db.

```
double lower;
double upper;
```

And want to make a new ResourceQueryValue (subclass of QueryValue) which looks the same as QueryValue used to:

```
int id;
String uri;
String name;
```

Is there anyway I can make this work. That is have a generic QueryValue class, but have the correct subclass returned depending on the parameters that the JSON supplies.

If I have not been clear please do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Gson does not currently have a simple mechanism for polymorphic deserialization, other than implementing custom deserialization processing.  The next release looks like it will provide a built-in solution.

Previous StackOverflow.com Questions And Answers (Some With Examples) On This Topic:

- [Deserialising a generic with unknown compile time type where a field indicates the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450935)
- [Parse JSON with no specific structure for a field with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089193)
- [json object serialization/deserialization using google gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528933)
- [Polymorphism with gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800433)

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, using Jackson might be the simplest solution (reading this http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to create a [custom deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ) if you need to check the values, or an [instance creator](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-an-Instance-Creator) if you only need to create an instance based on type.

Comment: Thanks Kaj, I missed the instance creator explanation for some reason. I think that might be the way to go.

Comment: A custom InstanceCreator is probably not the route to take.  InstanceCreators are for creating objects with default values -- not for custom deserialization processing.  Note that by default they don't even have reference to the deserialization context -- because they're not intended to be used to replace custom deserializers.  InstanceCreators are useful when you absolutely have to use a particular constructor, and it's for some reason unacceptable for Gson to use the no-argument constructor (which it otherwise effectively uses, even if it's not provided by the coder or the compiler).