# Spring Boot Jackson Databind - Configure Inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

Suppose I have a base class `A`:

```
public class A {
    public String a;
}
```

And two child classes `B` and `C`:

```
public class B extends A {
    public String b;
}

public class C extends A {
    public String c;
}
```

And wrapper of `A` class:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public A a;
}
```

And I have Rest controller that receives client requests as wrapper object:

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    public void foo(@RequestBody Wrapper wrapper) {}

}
```

The problem is that Jackson casts wrapper field to base class `A`.

How can I configure it to recieve correct type?

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Comment: @shmosel I'm having such [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435062/jackson-deserialization-unexpected-token-end-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your base class `A` with type information that tells Jackson how to decide whether a given json object should be deserialized to `B.java` or `C.java`.

Ex: With the below code, we are telling jackson that json object for A.class will contain a property with key `type` whose value can be either "b" or "c". If the value is "b", deserialize the object to `B.class`, else deserialize it to `C.class`

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")  
@JsonSubTypes({  
    @Type(value = B.class, name = "b"),  
    @Type(value = B.class, name= "c")
    })  
class A {
}
```

Following is the json that you should be using.

```
{
   "a" : { // This will be deserialized to B.class
      "type": "b",
      // field of B.class
   }
}



{
   "a" : { // This will be deserialized to C.class
      "type": "c",
      // field of C.class
   }
}
```

Comment: I got it right but important thing was that base class cannot be instantiated. Base class should be `abstract` or `interface`.