# Parsing an object with variable type in gson

Tags: android, gson

I have something like the following json string:

```
{"values" : [
           { "group":"A"
             "rating":2
           },
           {
             "group":"B"
             "language":"english"
           }
         ]
}
```

As you can see, "values" is an array, with different type of objects. One type can contain a string and an integer, and the other type contains a string and another string.

How do I deal with this?

Comment: If I put the second variable as an integer, it gives an error while parsing the "group B" type of object, even though i'm "using" only "group A" type objects (i.e., I only use the first element of this array). I'm fully certain that the first element always has groupA elements, but I guess it has to parse all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't notice originally you wrote "gson". I'm not sure you can do it, and here's [not me saying it](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Limitations).

Comment: Apparently you can : http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java

Comment: RawCollectionsExample is not an example of polymorphic deserialization, which is how I'd preferably approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Do some thing like the following

```
List myStrings = new ArrayList();
    myStrings = gson.fromJson(json,myStrings.getClass());

    Iterator myIterator = myStrings.iterator();
    boolean b;
    while(myIterator.hasNext()){
        Object o =myIterator.next();
        b=o instanceof String;

        System.out.println("...."+b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would probably be to implement a polymorphic deserialization solution.

Gson does not currently have a simple mechanism for polymorphic deserialization, other than implementing custom deserialization processing.  The next release looks like it will provide a built-in solution.

Previous StackOverflow.com Questions And Answers (Some With Examples) On This Topic:

- [Deserialising a generic with unknown compile time type where a field indicates the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450935)
- [Parse JSON with no specific structure for a field with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089193)
- [json object serialization/deserialization using google gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528933)
- [Polymorphism with gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800433)

Specific to the original question, it looks like the "group" element would be used to distinguish between different types.

FWIW, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) released [a built-in solution to this problem](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) many moons ago.